# Mysql Select with concat where some fields are null

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a join between two tables to push criteria values into a record description. The problem is some records do not have some/all criteria and the entire string fails:

`Select Concat(Description,'<br><br>',C.CritieraNameA,': ',T.CriteriaValueA,'<br><br>',C.CriteriaNameB,': ',T.CriteriaValueB) 
From Records T
Inner Join Company C
On T.CompanyID=C.ID`

so I end up with

**Supermarket specializing in Dairy Products


Hours: 8am-5pm
Credit Cards: Yes**

and

**Gone with the Wind


Running Time: Too long

Format: DVD**

This works fine until I hit a record where either

- There is no CriteriaTypeA or CriteriaTypeB in the Company Table
- There is no CriteriaValueA or CriteriaValueB in the Records Table

Is there a way to do this select so when it doesn' find a CriteriaValue in Records:

**Supermarket specializing in Meats


Hours:

Credit Cards: Yes**

or a CriteriaName in Company:

**Porsche


Type: Sports Car**

It does not simply return an empty result?

Comment: Just select the columns and implement the output logic in your application language.

Comment: See CONCAT_WS()

Answer (score 1):

`IfNull` could be useful in this case - it will detect a null and replace it with a value you supply.

```
IFNULL(CriteriaTypeA , "not given")
```

Comment: The problem with this is I am doing formatting (sorry should have mentioned) with a colon so I can do `ifnull('',CriteriaTypeA)` but I cannot do `ifnull('',Concat(CriteriaTypeA,':')` Basically: don't put anything if no criteriatype found if one is found format it and add a semi-colon.  Right  now the `isnull` is considering the `'<br><br>'` to be true so I get empty even if the CriteriaType is not NULL

Answer (score 1):

Concat_WS to the rescue:

`Concat_WS('',C.CriteriaTypeA,': ',T.CriteriaValue)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Select Concat(
    Description,
    Coalesce(Concat('<br><br>',C.CritieraNameA,': ',T.CriteriaValueA), ''),
    Coalesce(Concat('<br><br>',C.CriteriaNameB,': ',T.CriteriaValueB), '')
) 
From Records T
Inner Join Company C
On T.CompanyID=C.ID
```

But as I wrote in the comment: Don't implement output logic in SQL.